# Solr SnowballPorterFilterFactory for index and query analyzers

Tags: search, solr, snowball, snowballanalyzer

I use **SnowballPorterFilterFactory** for index and query analyzers. 
When i search for "profession" word. Solr successfully finds only articles that contains "profession", but i want "professional" "professionalism" ...

This is the current configuration on **schema.xml**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>

    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I would suggest going to the Solr admin panel, clicking on `Analysis` and running a field analysis on this type. Do both the query and index ones and see whether they're getting stemmed the same way or not.

Comment: Also look at the Solr logs and see if the Porter filter factory is being loaded correctly, especially with the additional language tag or if it's throwing some kind of warning.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is porter is over-stemming your query. When you search for `profession` your keyword gets stemmed down to `profess`, whereas `profession` `professional` and `professionalism`  are all stored in the index as `profession`.

The only real way you are going to get around this is by adding another `fieldType` where you do not stem your query.

Something like:

```
<fieldType name="text_unstemmed_query" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

With a copyfield like:

`<copyField source="your_text_field" dest="text_unstem_query_field"/>`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue - I use the Porter stemmer myself and I've never faced this double-stemming issue before.

Comment: I ran his setup through the Solr analysis and this was the result I got. _Profession_ gets stemmed down to _profess_ and _professional_ gets stemmed to _profession_ in the index. They will not match with his current setup. That is why there is an analyzer type, one for storing content in the index and one for how to compare when running a query.

Comment: hi, thank's for your response, i verified my logs and used copyfield solution but the problem persiste, please note that i use edismax query parser. should i add the * on my q parameter ?  example : profession*

Comment: If he doesn't stem the query, it's not going to match what he has in the index. One (dirty) getaround however is to stem everything twice. That way everything will be the stemmed to the base.

Comment: There is no problem about the stem but the problem is to combine the stem with the * mark. so the Profession word is stemmed to profess and when i add * mark after prefess they don't find the articles with profess* => profession, professional...